# I need debugging tips for a broken project dependency

Tags: gradle, integration-testing

It's configured the same here as it is everywhere else. In fact I use an import for configuring integration tests. I've done everything I can think of including a rename of local integration test tasks and configurations, including looking at the dependency tree, including running with `--debug`. Yet for some reason Gradle insists that the property integrationTest doesn't exist on the sourceSet for an inter-project dependency:

```
integrationTestCompile project(':components:things-components:abc-stuff').sourceSets.integrationTest.output
```

...now I'm not particularly fond of this syntax and I've already griped up a storm about inter-project test dependencies and how they should be in a test utility component. However, I'm doing it this way because this appears to be what IntelliJ will accept. Writing like this causes trouble:

```
integrationTestCompile project(path: ':components:things-components:abc-stuff', configuration: 'integrationTest')
```

How can I figure this out?  I just don't get why only one project has this issue.

For the record, I've also tried:

```
integrationTestCompile project(path: ':components:things-components:abc-stuff', configuration: 'integrationTestCompile')
```

Comment: In `:components:things-components:abc-stuff` did you publish a jar on `integrationTest`?

Comment: No. No reason to since integration tests don't get deployed. Why spend the extra cycles?  As mentioned, it is configured the same everywhere. Nowhere in our build are tests JAR'ed. I suspect I've found a Gradle bug of some sort.  Of particular concern to me is that we might have traversed some sort of upper boundary since our build is huge. 100+ sub-projects with massive numbers of dependencies.

Comment: ...on second thought.... please elaborate? I'm trying this angle now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Gradle hasn't been told to make a jar for you that you can consume in your other project.

```
integrationTestCompile project(':components:things-components:abc-stuff').sourceSets.integrationTest.output
```

Gets the classFiles and the dependencies, thats why its working using that notation. If you want to use the `configuration` notation you will need to tell gradle to publish a jar on the `integrationTest`. The jar doesn't have to be published to a repository, but will be used for the internal builds.

You can do this by doing:

```
configurations {
    integrationTest
}

task integrationTestJar (type: Jar) {
    baseName = "${project.name}-integ-test"
    from sourceSets.integrationTest.output
}

artifacts {
    integrationTest integrationTestJar
}
```

If you end up doing this in a log of projects, I would recommend writing a quick plugin that does this for you.

Comment: Then why does it work everywhere else where no jars are specified? I think I've tried this already but will double check.  As mentioned previously, we have this block like so: apply from: "${rootProject.rootDir}/buildSrc/config/integrationTest.gradle"

Comment: When you do `sourceSets.integrationTest.output` you should be depending on a FileCollection which would contain the compiled class files. When you add an artifact to `integrationTest` then when you depend on just the `integrationTest` configuration it will have the jar and your dependencies.